# Firefox onclick not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, onclick

i have problem with Firefox and bxSlider. I do not know why onclick does not work.
Live preview [here](http://daniel.koptak.cz/webOndraFour/)

```js
        $(document).on('click', '.more', function () { 
            e.preventDefault();
            var heightSpan = $(this).parent().parent().find(".hide-text").height();
            var startHeight = $(".bx-viewport").height();
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".hide-text").css("display", "block");
            $(".bx-viewport").animate({ height: startHeight + heightSpan+15 }, 200);
            $(this).parent().html('<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle rem" data-height="' + startHeight +'"></div>');
            $("#bx-pager .active").click();
        });
```

In Chrome is everything okay but in Firefox Quantum is problem... onclick in jQuery or in JavaScript not work.

Where is the error?

Comment: Check if your browser (Firefox) has JavaScript disabled

Comment: No clue how chrome would work with that code snipplet. Error message in the console should be quite noticeable! declare `e`

Comment: Some browsers make the event object global, while some do not.  If you are going to use the event, you should pass it in for consistency.

Comment: I just went to your "preview" in FF and it worked fine. Unless there is something I'm missing?

Comment: When I click on "plus button" (class: more) than not unroll paragraph... another scripts work fine

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the web console?

Comment: Console in Firefox/Chrome no errors

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you never pass the argument *e* into the function, so this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.more', function () { 
            e.preventDefault(); //Problem happens here
            ...
        });
```

Should be made into this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.more', function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            ...
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9a739b0h/3/

This solves the problem of not being able to cause an effect by clicking, but I'm not sure what the second issue is(if there is one, I didn't understand it properly).

Comment: Not work... here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hhmovz5v/3/
onclick "here" in Chrome is OK but in Firefox not work, I do not know where is problem...